# autossh in background does not work

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have set up a tunnel via autossh.

This works:

```
autossh -M 33201 -N -i myIdFile -R 33101:localhost:22 autossh@myhost.com
```

I would like to run autossh in background. Seems easy using the `-f` option.

This does not work, however:

```
autossh -f -M 33201 -N -i myIdFile -R 33101:localhost:22 autossh@myhost.com
```

Autossh runs in the background fine, but the ssh connection seems to fail every time. In /var/syslog I see multiple occurences of:

```
autossh[3420]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
```

What am I doing wrong? A wild guess is it has something to do with the authentication via key file. How can I debug this (adding -v to the ssh options does not seem to log anywhere).

**Edit:**
I got some ssh logs using the -y option

```
/usr/bin/ssh[3484]: debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
/usr/bin/ssh[3484]: debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
/usr/bin/ssh[3484]: debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
/usr/bin/ssh[3484]: debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
/usr/bin/ssh[3484]: debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
/usr/bin/ssh[3484]: fatal: Permission denied (publickey).
autossh[3469]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
```

So it seems autossh does not accept my identiy file (`-i myIdFile`) when using the -f option. Why is that?

(autossh 1.4c on Raspian)

Comment: Why use autossh at all? You can use systemd for the "restart on failure stuff". I created a gist with my solution: https://gist.github.com/guettli/31242c61f00e365bbf5ed08d09cdc006#file-ssh-tunnel-service

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It seems like when autossh drops to the background (-f option) it is changing the working directory, meaning relative paths do not work any longer. Or more specific: By **entering the absolute path of your id file** you will probably succeed.

I re-created the scenario by creating a key with no password at a non-default location:

```
~/$ mkdir test
~/$ cd test
~/test$ ssh-keygen -f test_id_rsa
```

I simply hit enter twice to generate a key that is not protected by a password.

I copied the new key to my server (which allows password authentication currently):

```
~/test$ ssh-copy-id -i test_id_rsa user@server
```

First I confirmed the key was working with regular ssh, then using autossh like you:

```
~/test$ ssh -i test_id_rsa user@server
~/test$ autossh -M 13000 -N -i test_id_rsa user@server
^C
```

They both worked fine, so I recreated the problem you had:

```
~/test$ autossh -f -M 13000 -N -i test_id_rsa user@server
```

This did not work and the following was written to `/var/log/syslog`:

> autossh[2406]: ssh exited prematurely with status 255; autossh exiting

By changing the path of the keyfile to be absolute, it worked though:

```
~/test$ autossh -f -M 13000 -N -i /home/user/test/test_id_rsa user@server
```

No errors in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: awesome, this works.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: The -N option is important, otherwise you'd get "ssh exited with status 0; autossh exiting". Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed, I too just had to add the path to the "id_rsa" file like so: autossh -M 19001 -fN -y -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa (thanks @jmidgren)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is going on with the -f but you could also nohup it:

```
nohup autossh -M 33201 -N -f -i myIdFile -R 33101:localhost:22 autossh@myhost.com &
```

Comment: nohup works for me, even without specifying the key file.

Comment: `nohup` also worked for running `autossh` under `runit` in Alpine Linux

Answer (score 0):

Add the following parameters to SSH to bypass "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"

```
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

The final command would be in the following format:

```
autossh -f -M $BASE_PORT -N -R $LOCAL_PORT:$LOCALHOST:$REMOTE_PORT $USER@$SERVER -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Comment: it works for me.

Comment: Don't enable `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` unless you're connecting to a known-good ephemeral toy -- and you're choosing to be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the host key fingerprint got reset and caused a 255 error.

Trying to establish a normal SSH session fixed the problem for autossh by adding the machine back to the known hosts:

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[XXXXXXXXXXXXX]:22' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
```

`systemctl status autossh.service` worked immediately after the above step (across reboots as well).