# Unable to use autossh in background even with absolute path

Tags: ssh

I would love to set autossh to run at boot adding it to `/etc/rc.local`.

This command works:

`autossh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 2522:localhost:22 user@address`

But, if I add the `-f` option

`autossh -f -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 2522:localhost:22 user@address`

The ssh session is not started.

As you can see, I'm using an absolute path for my identity file, so this seems to be a different problem from the one stated here: [autossh in background does not work](https://serverfault.com/questions/534229/autossh-in-background-does-not-work)

From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 18 11:08:39 raspberrypi autossh[2417]: starting ssh (count 1)
Oct 18 11:08:39 raspberrypi autossh[2417]: ssh child pid is 2418
Oct 18 11:08:39 raspberrypi autossh[2417]: ssh exited with status 0; autossh exiting
```

I'm using it with debian wheezy on a raspberry pi, autossh version 1.4c.

Could it be that it's passing the `-f` option to ssh instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you start autossh without `-f`, you get a shell. While the shell is working, you get port forwarding. After you logout, ssh terminates with exit code 0 and autossh knows it does not need to launch ssh session again.

When you start autossh with `-f`, it passes `-f` to ssh too. ssh is then running in the background and does not give you a shell. As you did not specify any other flags or remote command, ssh exits immediately with status 0 (nothing to do), and autossh does not start it over.

Just add `-N` option to avoid it:

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding
        ports (protocol version 2 only)
```

Like this:

```
autossh -f -N -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 2522:localhost:22 user@address
```

Comment: This seems to work, but contradicts what the man page says:

`-f  causes autossh to drop to the background before running ssh. The -f flag is stripped from arguments passed to ssh.`